# How to manage different labels in a bar chart, taking data from a text file?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new in using matplotlib, so I'm having some problems. I must create a bar chart with different labels, for each website that I have.
The file is like the following:

```
1001 adblock 12
1001 badger 11
1001 disconnect 15
1001 ghostery 15
1001 nottrack 14
1001 origin 15
1001 policy 16
1001 ultimate 14
4ruote adblock 12
4ruote badger 1
4ruote disconnect 14
4ruote ghostery 27
4ruote nottrack 9
4ruote origin 26
4ruote policy 34
4ruote ultimate 20
...... ........ ...
```

My goal is to create a bar chart in which I have:

1. on the x axis sites (first column of the file), is a string
2. on the y axis the values (third column of the file) for that site (that are 8 times repeated inside the file), so 8 integer values
3. labels that, for a specific site, are present in the second column (strings).

I read different answers but each one didn't threat this comparison between labels, for a same variable.
What I'm doing is read the file, splitting the row and taking the first and third column, but how can I manage the labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`seaborn` does this neatly:

```
from pandas import read_csv
from matplotlib.pyplot import show
from seaborn import factorplot

fil = read_csv('multi_bar.txt', sep=r'\s*', engine='python', header=None)
fil.columns=['site','type','value']

factorplot(data=fil, x='site', y='value', hue='type', kind='bar')

show()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh very good!! this is perfectly what I wanted to obtain, but I want to ask you just one think: in the first part (1001 website), why the last bar has not been plotted for adblock, even if I have in the file:

Comment: 1001 adblock 12, that should plot a high bar of 12!!

Comment: Good catch! `read_csv` assumes the first row is a header row, not data. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have read the websites into 8 different datasets (adblock, badger, disconnect, etc). You can then use the logic below to plot each series and show their labels on a legend.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#this is your number of datasets
x = numpy.arange(8)
width = 0.1
#plot each dataset here, offset by the width of the preceding bars
b1 = ax.bar(x, adblock, width, color='r')
b2 = ax.bar(x + width, badger, color='g')
b3 = ax.bar(x + width*2, disconnect, color='m')
legend([b1[0], b2[0], b3[0]], ['adblock', 'badger',
                                          'disconnect'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: So am I able to plot for a specific website the comparison between the different datasets? Because I'm trying to read the file row by row and. Is there another simple way to do that?

Comment: I am confused by your question - this approach will give a plot similar to that shown here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html. Where men, women, etc would be your websites.

Comment: I mean: in which way can I collect data in datasets? because I'm new in python and I know that is possible with a dictionary (so for each site and plugin -> plot...). But my question is: is there a simple way to construct this dataset directly working with the obtained file above?

Comment: Anyway, I saw that graph and it is exactly what I want to obtain. But in that example data were passed manually and not taken in a file.. so I'm in trouble..

Comment: Even better, what I want to obtain is the list of websites on the X axis, on the Y the values, and as labels (for each site) the different plugins. So is yet different from the solution proposed by you.

Comment: You could read the file in using pandas as explained in the answer below. If the file is in a csv format, you can read it directly into a dataframe as explained here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html. This allows you to reference each dataset by column name ('site','plugin','value') in your case. The way that I've explained it in my answer should plot the values as you have proposed.